# Angular Material and IE : Can't layout-align="center center" in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I am new to Angular Material Design so I have some trouble making webapps cross-browser. 
[Here's my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXZ3e.png)

These 3 items are stacked on IE but not on Chrome and Firefox.

And I want them to be exactly like on Chrome/Firefox

Apparently the problem is coming from "layout-align='center center'" because if I just use "layout-align='center'" they're not stacked on IE anymore but they're appearing [aligned on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm8Iw.png) on every browser.

Here's the HTML:

```
  <div layout="column" layout-align="center center" style="text-align:center;" style="min-height:400px" ng-repeat="(title,score) in results.scoreByCategories">
    <h4>{{title}} :</h4>
    <div layout="row" layout-xs="column" >
      <div flex>
        <p id="button-debutant" class="rcorners">Débutant</p>
      </div>
      <div flex>
        <p id="button-intermediaire" class="rcorners">Intermédiaire</p>
      </div>
      <div flex>
        <p id="button-confirme" class="rcorners">Confirmé</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's my CSS :

```
.rcorners{
    color: grey;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 20px;
    float:left;
    margin: 5px 12px
}
```

Feel free to point out my mistakes! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for your problem

You only have to replace this block of code (written by you)

```
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column" >
  <div flex>
    <p id="button-debutant" class="rcorners">Débutant</p>
  </div>
  <div flex>
    <p id="button-intermediaire" class="rcorners">Intermédiaire</p>
  </div>
  <div flex>
    <p id="button-confirme" class="rcorners">Confirmé</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

with this one:

```
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-align="center center" >
    <div>
        <p id="button-debutant" class="rcorners">Débutant</p>
    </div>
    <div >
        <p id="button-intermediaire" class="rcorners">Intermédiaire</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p id="button-confirme" class="rcorners">Confirmé</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically you will force IE to consider the three button as an unique row, while the  `layout-align="center center"` written before (where there is the `ng-repeat`) will align the whole portion of page in the center of the page (both vertically and horizontally). I don't why IE requires this little extra work but it works :)

I hope I helped you